# How do I change the log level for airflow/composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

The info logging on airflow is way too much for my taste, so how do I change the log level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg

Line 55

```
# Logging level
logging_level = INFO
```

Comment: thanks, but where do I change that when using composer?

Comment: I think it out. There is config override settings in composer.